# progressbar during postbacks asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

What is the best way to show the user progress of inserting records by using procress bar in `asp.net`.
And After Process Complete then show a Message that data inserted.
Can i do this using `Javascript` and `Jquery`?

Comment: If you look carefully there's already a progress bar in your browser. Depending on which browser you are using it might be situated on a different place. For example on Google Chrome it's next to the title of the webpage on the tab. When you send an HTTP request to your server a small spinner starts to roll indicating that the browser is loading some data from the server.

Comment: -1 Darin, that's an awful, suggestion. That is almost like saying, ohhh don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you must understand there is no easy way to it.

You must do `pooling` or `web sockets` or `long pooling`,
that means that you have to ask the server in background if he is finished the job.

```
Here is couple of examples to so:
```

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

`here is on with SignalR` 
http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/12/26/real-time-progress-bar-using-jquery-ui-and-signalr/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx